# C++ and CLR Stored Procedures

Tags: c++, stored-procedures

Does anybody know if possible to run a CLR SQL Server Stored Procedure in c++?

And if you could provide sample code on how to call a CLR stored procedure.

Note: I do not mean managed c++ aka C++ CLR

Example)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did it so I do not know if the current versions of sql server still support this.  We used to write unmanaged c++ extended stored procedures.  MS may have taken it away because they are so unsafe.  Here is an article.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/extended_sp.aspx